# Opencv 2.2 not recognized on Python 2.7 (Ubuntu/Windows XP)

Tags: python, opencv, installation, integration

I've been trying to connect opencv and python in both Ubuntu and Windows XP. I've failed on both.

I've read many webpages and threads about "how to install" it but none has worked (the worst part is that they all say kind of the same).

Steps (windows xp):

- Installed Python 2.7 by default (works perfectly)
- Installed PIL and cx_Freeze (may they
  create a conflict? I don't think so
  :s)
- Installed Opencv 2.2 by default
  (OpenCV-2.2.0-win32-vs2010.exe) and
  it isn't recognized inside a py nor
  as import opencv.cv nor using the
  cookbook way, import cv (I skipped
  the visual studio steps since I'll
  use it with python)
- Checked path (it's ok, it has the
  Opencv2.2\bin thing)
- Rechecked webpages and stuff

Steps (ubuntu):

- Had python working
- sudo apt-get install, cmake, make,
  sudo make install, etcetc (from the
  tutorials)
- same thing... module not recognized

Please can you help?

**Update:**

I managed to install it and have it recognized by the system (I used http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#opencv and it worked perfectly after that).

The problem now is that it crashes when I try to use `CaptureFromFile`. Someone else has reported it 3 days ago so now I wait.

I'll check the other wrappers, maybe one of them will work.

Answer (score 1):

For windows see my web page: http://www.modernmind.org/wiki/OpenCV

For Ubuntu you should just need to apt-get install python-dev then generate the make files with Cmake, build it and then make install. In order to build the python bindings you need to have the python header files on your system and you probably don't. When you run configure in Cmake make sure that you don't see any messages at the top about PYTHON_INCLUDE not being defined.

Answer (score 0):

To access a library it needs a Python library installed in the Python version you are using. From what you write above it seems to me that you install OpenCV in general, but that you don't specifically install the Python library. This is why it doesn't work.

I'm not sure how to install the Python wrappers, and the OpenCV documentation is a bit sparse on that info. But if you did build them (and that needs to be turned on explicitly, says the docs) they seem to end up in opencv/release/lib .

Look at "Testing Python wrappers" on http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/InstallGuide

If there is still no luck, there is a bunch of alternative Python wrappers available: http://pypi.python.org/pypi?%3Aaction=search&term=opencv&submit=search

Maybe they are better documented.